# why python function is not finding the global variable?

Tags: python, function, global-variables

```
    def bToDLL(,root):
        # do Code here
    
        h,p = None, None
        def sol(r):
            global h,p
            if(r == None): return None
        
            sol(r.left)
            
            if(p == None): h = r
            else:
                r.left = p
                p.right = r
            
            p = r
            
            sol(r.right)
            
        sol(root)  
            
        return(h)
```

but this is showing this error:

```
  File "/home/f03e32e9d366ee3e9a5adb9d71436496.py", line 33, in bToDLL
    sol(root)  
  File "/home/f03e32e9d366ee3e9a5adb9d71436496.py", line 22, in sol
    sol(r.left)
  File "/home/f03e32e9d366ee3e9a5adb9d71436496.py", line 24, in sol
    if(p == None): h = r
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
```

i have defined the var p in global scope! ,and have marked it as global inside function too but why it is not finding it ?

Comment: Because you did `h,p = None, None`.  That make "p" a local to the `bToDLL` function, not a global.  What you should do is replace `global` with `nonlocal`.

Comment: In this example, `h` and `p` are not `global`. - "global" is the module level namespace.